# How to find max and min element in a LinkedList most efficiently?

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a linked list in Java ,say , `LinkedList<T> list = new LinkedList<T>();` and I need to find the max / min element in it most efficiently , how can I do it?

How can I use `Collections.max()` function to find the max element from my linked list? What is the time complexity of this function ?

Comment: The complexity is O(n), of course.

Comment: It is obviously linear in the number of elements (see Javadoc of `Collections`)

Comment: I don't get the "how can I use it" part of the question, could you explain?

Comment: How will i call Collections.max() for my linked list ?

Comment: @sTEAK. you just call it. It's a method. You call it.

Comment: @sTEAK. Just pass your list as the argument.

Comment: `Object o = Collections.max(yourList);`

Comment: @Baz  When i pass the list as argument it doesnt work.

Comment: @sTEAK. in what way? What's in the list?

Comment: Make sure the elements implement `Comparable` interface or pass a `Comparator` to the `Collections.max()` as second parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The time complexity is `O(n)` if you want it to be lower e.g. `O(1)` you need to use a different data structure such as a TreeSet.

> how can i use Collections.max() for LinkedList

```
List<Integer> list = ...
Integer max = Collections.max(list);
```

Comment: ... where he'll just pay the price upfront :)

Comment: how can i use `Collections.max()` for LinkedList ?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik if you do it repeatedly with small updates to the collection in between than it makes certain sense

Comment: @Qnan Yes, good point. There's less cost if you need to re-evaluate often.

Comment: don't you mean O(logN)? you still need to search the tree. The only way i see it hapenning in O(1) is using PriorityQueue as maxHeap

Comment: @JAsgarov TreeSet is O(Log N) for insert, but O(1) for the minimum value

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
/* fill with values */
Integer max = Collections.max(numbers);
```

Comment: It should be `Collections.max(numbers);`

Answer (score 0):

**Java Doc**

> This method iterates over the entire collection, hence it requires time proportional to the size of the collection. (O(n))

**Usage**

```
public class Test
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    // create an LinkedList object
    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    // Add elements to LinkedList
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(3);
    list.add(4);
    list.add(5);

    //Use Max Method
    System.out.println(Collections.max(list));
}
}
```

---

Comment: is there any point in adding the third answer to a silly question, that contains no new information?

Comment: @Qnan Untill I pressed `Post your Answer` there were already two answers :)

Comment: yep, it takes speed here on SO :D

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `stream.max()` to get the max value of a LinkedList

```
LinkedList<Integer> linkedList = new LinkedList<>();

linkedList.add(1); linkedList.add(2);
linkedList.add(3); linkedList.add(4);

linkedList.stream().max(Integer::compareTo).ifPresent(System.out::println);

Output: 4
```